# Finding a constant form the joint probability density function

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

Given that the joint probability density function associated with two continuous random
variables X and Y is given by f(x,y): \begin{cases}
Pe^{-y}, & \text{− y < x < y and 0 < y < ∞ } \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

I need to find the value of the constant P.

I know that to do this I need to find the double integral which will equal 1. However I'm confused as to what the limits for the double integral will be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as you said

$$1= \int_{\Bbb R^2} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$$

Now, the limits of $y$ are $0$ and $\infty$ and of $x$ are $-y $ and $y$ so you get

$$1 = \int_0^{\infty} \int_{-y}^{y} Pe^{-y}dx dy $$